# Persistent GCLOUD APP DEPLOY on updating after having deleted versions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

when I execute : gcloud app deploy

Here is what I'm getting

```
descriptor:      [E:\quizz\0.0.3\app.yaml]
source:          [E:\quizz\0.0.3]
target project:  [quiz-fnec]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200329t214116]
target url:      [https://quiz-fnec.appspot.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 421bc274-7963-496b-872d-5f92d10a050e status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"CBD4CA7E","errorMessage":"INFO     FTL version node-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for node\nINFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository eu.gcr.io/quiz-fnec/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name eu.gcr.io/quiz-fnec/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:a10e9367-04c3-433f-b4cb-ede3162edf4b\nINFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00\nINFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.gaeconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity NOTSET\nINFO     starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00'\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/quiz-fnec/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:a10e9367-04c3-433f-b4cb-ede3162edf4b'\nINFO     Found neither yarn.lock or package-lock.json,generating package-lock.json from package.json\nINFO     starting: gen_package_lock\nINFO     gen_package_lock npm install --package-lock-only\nINFO     `gen_package_lock` stdout:\nadded 442 packages from 25 contributors and audited 1295 packages in 10.942s\nfound 7 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 moderate, 2 high)\n  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details\n\nINFO     `gen_package_lock` had stderr output:\nnpm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)\nnpm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.\nnpm WARN quizzapi@0.0.3 No description\nnpm WARN quizzapi@0.0.3 No repository field.\n\n\nINFO     gen_package_lock took 11 seconds\nINFO     builder initialization took 11 seconds\nINFO     starting: build process for FTL image\nINFO     starting: rm_node_modules\nINFO     rm_node_modules rm -rf /workspace/node_modules\nINFO     `rm_node_modules` stdout:\n\nINFO     rm_node_modules took 0 seconds\nINFO     using descriptor:package-lock.json\nINFO     using descriptor:package.json\nINFO     starting: checking_cached_packages_json_layer\nDEBUG    Checking cache for cache_key 511911033f429f42faff5273bbdf5c8316a497e1627c173e5c7274e193618043\nINFO     No cached base image found for entry: eu.gcr.io/quiz-fnec/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache:511911033f429f42faff5273bbdf5c8316a497e1627c173e5c7274e193618043.\nINFO     Cache miss on local cache for eu.gcr.io/quiz-fnec/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache:511911033f429f42faff5273bbdf5c8316a497e1627c173e5c7274e193618043\nINFO     No cached dependency layer for 511911033f429f42faff5273bbdf5c8316a497e1627c173e5c7274e193618043\nINFO     [CACHE][MISS] v0.17.0:NODE-\u003e511911033f429f42faff5273bbdf5c8316a497e1627c173e5c7274e193618043\nINFO     checking_cached_packages_json_layer took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: building_packages_json_layer\nINFO     starting: npm_install\nINFO     npm_install npm install --production\nINFO     `npm_install` stdout:\n\n\u003e grpc@1.24.2 install /workspace/node_modules/grpc\n\u003e node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library\n\n[grpc] Success: \"/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node\" is installed via remote\n\n\u003e bcrypt@3.0.8 i.
Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/421bc274-7963-496b-872d-5f92d10a050e?project=146717279495
```

Can't update or delete the default version of Gcloud app deploy here is my server (nodejs api) and yaml configuration : 
Yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

Comment: Have you checked the link the error message provides? There may be something useful. I also recommend you to deploy being more verbose (`gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug`) and see if it provides any hint as for the failure's reason.

Comment: I checked the link provided and it does output the following (I couldn't spot a clear error)

Comment: What output did you get from the verbose deploy? Did you find anything new on the logs?

Comment: Curiously `Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage`. Suggests the deployment isn't finding your sources. It expects a `package.json` and some JavaScript alongside `app.yaml`